# Last xe(la)tex colors text in white in some circumstances

Tags: xetex, color, texlive, tcolorbox

Last `xe(la)tex`:

```
XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (preloaded format=xelatex 2014.6.19)
```

(the one shipped with TeX Live 2014) colors text in white in some circumstances: in the following MWE file compiled with `xelatex`, the "Lorem Ipsum" text after the outer `tcolorbox` environment on page 2 is colored in white.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
%
\begin{document}
%
\rule{0.4pt}{17cm}
%
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
  Foo.
  \begin{tcolorbox}
    foo

    foo

    foo

    foo
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
% \color{black}%
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

It must be noticed that the trouble still arises if the `\color{black}` is uncommented but doesn't arise:

- with older `xe(la)tex`:

  ```
  XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (format=xelatex 2013.7.9)
  ```

  (e.g. the one shipped with TeX Live 2013), even with `tcolorbox` package shipped with TeX Live 2014 (version 3.05): hence `tcolorbox` seems to not be responsible of the trouble by itself,
- if the file is compiled with `pdflatex`,
- in the MWE above if the `breakable` option of the outer `tcolorbox` environment is dropped.

Comment: The inner tcolorbox is not needed. A `\lipsum[1]` instead shows the problem too. The problem seems to be with xdvipdfmx (which is newer in TL14 than in miktex). If I compile a xdv created by TL14 with the xdvipdfmx of miktex the output is fine. Also the color reappears if on use the `-c` option of xdvipdfmx. I suggest that you make a bug report at `tex-k@tug.org`.

Comment: Bug report [done](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-k/2014-June/002552.html).

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the problem with MiKTeX as you know. But recently I was put to another XeLaTeX related problem which was reproducable with MiKTeX. I think I found a solution which hopefully also solves (or circumvents) your problem. Please, test if the following works on your system: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193318/using-paracol-with-breakable-box-tcolorbox/193541#193541

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Maybe, you are also interested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193318/using-paracol-with-breakable-box-tcolorbox/193541#193541  I have some hopes that this also works with TeXLive but I have no system with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text color implementation of `tcolorbox` was changed to circumvent another `xelatex` related color problem. Denis Bitouzé informed me that this also solved the problem of this question. Since I don't use TeX Live I cannot check myself, but, certainly, I trust the OP :-)

So the answer is: Update to `tcolorbox` version `3.12 (2014/07/29)` or newer.

Comment: For future reference, I confirmed that you are correct. See closed question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287580/13552

Comment: A problem with `listings` still exists. See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308672/why-is-text-turning-white-possible-scope-leak-after-page-break-and-listings

Comment: @macmadness86 On my system, this problem seems to be solved (by XeTeX ?).

Answer (score 3):

read below text (form: http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2014-June/025331.html)

I have confirmed that, in the case of dvipdfmx,

> \documentclass[dvipdfm]{article}
>   is ok, but
>   \documentclass[dvipdfmx]{article}
>   is ng.
>
> Therefore the bug may be in dvipdfmx.def and xetex.def.

However, `latex --> dvi --> dvipdfmx --> pdf`
for

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{article}
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\begin{document}
%
\rule{0.4pt}{17cm}
%
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

and xelatex for

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\begin{document}
%
\rule{0.4pt}{17cm}
%
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

generate good results.
Thus problems are in pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def and pgfsys-xetex.def.

Best,
Akira