# xelatex and tcolorbox incompatibility?

Tags: xetex, tcolorbox

I have a serious problem when using xelatex with tcolorbox: the text that follows a breakable tcolorbox simply disappear!
The problem does not arise with pdflatex, just with xelatex.
I am using TexLive (MacTeX) 2014 and tcolorbox 3.05.

Here is a minimal working example: you can switch between xelatex and pdflatex by changing the first (commented) line in many tex editors, e.g. TeXshop.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex 

\documentclass[11pt,usletter]{book}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=test, breakable]
\blindtext[4]
\end{tcolorbox}
\blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186139/last-xelatex-colors-text-in-white-in-some-circumstances and the thread on the xetex mailing list starting here http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/xetex/2014-June/025326.html

Comment: With some hope, the current development version described in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193318/using-paracol-with-breakable-box-tcolorbox/193541#193541 solves / circumvents the problem.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Please, add an answer when the version of `tcolorbox` solving the problem is deployed. With 3.11 the problem is still present.

Comment: @egreg Unfortunately, I have no feedback from anyone using xelatex with TeXLive 2014 yet. Since I don't use TeXLive 2014, I cannot tell if the problem is really solved/circumvented with 3.12. As soon as I have a positive feedback, I will give an answer here. :-)

Comment: Could you try if `tcolorbox` version `3.12 (2014/07/29)` solves or circumvents your problem? I cannot test myself. Also, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186139/last-xelatex-colors-text-in-white-in-some-circumstances/201611#201611

Comment: @egreg Maybe, you could try if the problem vanished with version `3.12 (2014/07/29)`? I've changed the implementation to circumvent a similar problem.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm It seems to work well now.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for testing. I've added an answer now.

Answer (score 2):

The text color implementation of `tcolorbox` version `3.12 (2014/07/29)` was changed to circumvent some other xelatex related color problems. The related problems are [using paracol with breakable box (tcolorbox)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193318/using-paracol-with-breakable-box-tcolorbox) and [Last xe(la)tex colors text in white in some circumstances](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186139/last-xelatex-colors-text-in-white-in-some-circumstances). @egreg confirmed that this also solved your problem.

Let me know, if you still have a problem after updating to tcolorbox version `3.12 (2014/07/29)` or newer.