# Text is white coloured after Beamer note pages when compiled with xelatex

Tags: beamer, xetex

I have a Beamer presentation with note pages, in which everything renders just fine with pdflatex.

However, when the file is compiled using **xelatex** (I need to use `fontspec`), texts in frames *after* a note page are not visible -- they are rendered in white colour. This problem is reproducible when using Beamer v3.33.

```
%% Compile with xelatex
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\mode<handout>
{
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\RequirePackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
A test, A test!
\note{ }
\end{frame}    

\begin{frame}
This text does not appear!
\note{ }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

While this problem can be solved by compiling with **lualatex**, I'm wondering if there's any thing one can do to make it work for **xelatex**?

Comment: This seems to be related to the problem described in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188174/xelatex-and-tcolorbox-incompatibility and discussed in http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/xetex/2014-June/025326.html

Comment: Try adding the `fragile` option as such \begin{frame}[fragile] ... \end{frame}.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Thanks for the links. Looks like it's something to do with the drivers.

Comment: @Jesse Nope, doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I verified your invisible page on my side, added fragile then the invisible page becomes visible. But later on, I disabled the fragile option, the visible page is still there. Sorry, my bad. Should have tested more before commenting.

Comment: related bug report github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/337

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, one can reset to normal colour at the begin of every frame:

```
%% Compile with xelatex
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\mode<handout>
{
    \setbeameroption{show notes}
    \RequirePackage{pgfpages}
    \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
}

\makeatletter 
\def\beamer@framenotesbegin{% at beginning of slide
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
    \gdef\beamer@noteitems{}% 
    \gdef\beamer@notes{}% 
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        A test, A test!
        \note{ }
    \end{frame}    

    \begin{frame}
        This text does not appear!
        \note{ }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked for me.