# Beamer: no text after title page with "show notes on second screen" using XeLaTeX

Tags: beamer, xetex, pgfpages

### Problem

I want to show notes on the second screen in my XeLaTeX beamer presentation but this causes all text to disappear after the title page. How can I get the text to be shown?

### Minimal Working Example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain]
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
\begin{document}                                                                                                      

\begin{frame}
This text is shown.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
This text is NOT shown.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

## Versions

```
$ xelatex --version
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016/TeX Live for SUSE Linux)
kpathsea version 6.2.2
[...]
Compiled with ICU version 52.1; using 52.1
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.8; using 1.2.8
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.6.3; using 2.6.3
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.3.1; using 1.3.1
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 1.4.5; using 1.4.5
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.8; using 1.6.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.42.0
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.11.1; using 2.11.1
```

Comment: The text is shown, the problem is the text colour. For a workaround, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/291545/36296

Comment: related bug report https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/337