# Beamer content disappears when notes are shown besides slides

Tags: beamer, pgfpages

I have finally encountered an exciting TeX-related problem to post here:
Using beamer slides with notes, certain parts of my slides disappear in the main slide when the option `\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}` in combination with the `pgfpages` package is used.

When i disable the option / only compile the slides without notes, the output is fine. However, using the option, the main slide view is missing text inbetween two `itemize`-environments as well as an `equation`.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}

\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item content
\item more content
\end{itemize}
\note{a note}
\pause
aaaand
\begin{itemize}
\item content
\item more content
\end{itemize}
\begin{equation}
A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

My question is: How can I make the annoted slides show the content that disappears when the notes are shown?

[image]

What I find exciting about his problem in particular is that for the preview above the nodes, the content missing from the slide is shown!

Comment: assuming that you are using xelatex: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/337

Comment: Thank you! I was able to use a workaround described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213053/text-is-white-coloured-after-beamer-note-pages-when-compiled-with-xelatex, as linked in the issue. Do I answer this question myself now or should I mark it as a duplicate?