# using paracol with breakable box (tcolorbox)

Tags: xetex, tcolorbox, paracol

see this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{paracol}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}

\begin{rightcolumn}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{rightcolumn}
\begin{leftcolumn}
\lipsum
\end{leftcolumn}

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

compiled with XeLaTeX the breakable box in the right side Cause displacement of text on the left

[image]
how we can fix this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this output. Where your red arrow is, I have the rest of the text for the left column. I also tried with an older version of `tcolorbox` without problems. I compiled with `pdflatex`.

Comment: Forgot to say that I use XeLaTeX to compile my code

Comment: I am compelled to use XeLaTeX For its ability of employment  of Fonts System

Comment: With XeLaTeX I can reproduce the problem. But at the moment I do not have an idea why pdflatex and XeLaTeX produce different output in this case.

Comment: The text on the left side is not displaced but written in white (or with opactiy 0). I think this is related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186139/last-xelatex-colors-text-in-white-in-some-circumstances and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188174/xelatex-and-tcolorbox-incompatibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text on the left hand side is not displaced but written with white color. The reason is a color stack problem resulting from vsplitting. `pdflatex` and `xelatex` seem to have a different color implementation.

I changed the placing of text colors for `tcolorbox` with the recent version `3.12 (2014/07/29)`.

This version was tested with MiKTeX. The following test file compiled without problems with different engines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{paracol}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}

\begin{rightcolumn}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,enhanced jigsaw,
  size=small,colback=red!10!white,colupper=blue!50!black,
  vfill before first,height fixed for=middle,
  pad at break=1mm]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{rightcolumn}
\begin{leftcolumn}
\lipsum
\end{leftcolumn}

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

I compiled with three engines:

> This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=xelatex 2014.6.23)

and

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.6.27)

and

> This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013062820 (rev 4627)  (format=lualatex 2013.12.20)

All three produced the same output:

> [image]

Note that it is still possible to provoke color errors in combination with `paracol`, if color commands are written into the box text. These errors appear for `tcolorbox` and `mdframed` alike. If this happens, it seems to be enough to place a `\color{.}` inside the column where colors disappear or are set wrong. This also worked in my experiment for `tcolorbox` and `mdframed` alike. If no color commands are written into the box text, I found no problems with the development version using MiKTeX.

Comment: I've downloaded the tcolorbox 3.12pre1 and Everything works well , thanks for this awesome package and for your efforts to  improve it Good luck .

Comment: @seloumi Glad I could help :-) The final version 3.12 is out now on [GitHub](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox) and will be available at [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) soon. Note that I added the `vfill before first` option to the example code.

Answer (score 2):

with `mdframed` we can put a breakable box without causing shift  of text in the left column

```
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}

\begin{rightcolumn}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=red!10]
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}

\end{rightcolumn}
\begin{leftcolumn}
\lipsum
\end{leftcolumn}

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

and we got

[image]